# Optimal Batch Size PostgreSQL Update

Tags: ruby, postgresql, batch-file

I am using Postgres and I have a ruby task that updates the contents of an entire table at an hourly rate. Currently this is achieved by updating the table in batches. However, I am not exactly sure what the formula is for finding an optimal batch size. Is there a formula or standard for determining an appropriate batch size?

Comment: How big is the table? What kind of data do you update? Is it an condition update? Is there an index on the updated column? How long does the update take currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is no theoretical optimal batch size. The optimal batch size will surely depend on your application model, the internal structure and of the accessed tables, the query structure and so on. The only reliable way I see to determine its size is benchmarking.

There are some optimization tips that can help you build a faster application, buy these tips cannot be followed blindly because many of them have corner cases where cannot be applied successfully. Again, the way to determine if a change (adding an index, changing the batch size, enabling the query cache...) improves the performance is benchmarking before and after every single change.